# Python beautifulsoup to remove all tags/content with specific tag and text following

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup in python and want to remove everything from a string that are enclosed in a certain tag and have a specific non-closing tag with specific text following it. In this example, I want to remove all the documents that have type tag inside it with text of DOCA.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<body>
    <document>
        <type>DOCA
            <sequence>1
            <filename>DOCA.htm
            <description>FORM DOCA
            <text>
                <title>Form DOCA</title>
                <h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
    </document>
    <document>
        <type>DOCB
        <sequence>1
        <filename>DOCB.htm
        <description>FORM DOCB
        <text>
            <title>Form DOCB</title>
            <h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
    </document>
<body>
```

What I want to do is remove all `<document>` that have a `<type>` of **DOCA**. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
>>print(soup.find('document').find('type', text = re.compile('DOCA.*')))
None
```

Answer (score 3):

You can query all documents and then, within each document, query all types, check to see if `DOCA` exists in any of them, and delete the entire enclosing document if it does.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(..., 'html.parser')

for doc in soup.find_all('document'):
    for type in doc.find_all('type'):
        if 'DOCA' in type.text:
            doc.extract()
            break

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<body>

<document>
<type>DOCB
        <sequence>1
        <filename>DOCB.htm
        <description>FORM DOCB
        <text>
<title>Form DOCB</title>
<h5 align="left"><a href="#toc">Table of Contents</a></h5>
</text></description></filename></sequence></type></document>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `lambda` in the `find` method to select an element, eg:

```
soup.find('document').find(lambda tag : tag.name == 'type' and 'DOCA' in tag.text)
```

Then you can use `extract` or `decompose` to remove that element.

*Edit:*  use this expression to select all elements:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name == 'document' 
    and tag.find(lambda t:t.name == 'type' and 'DOCA' in t.text))
```

Comment: which method would be faster for large documents? using this lambda, or looping through as in @COLDSPEED 's answer?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. @COLDSPEED uses 2 loops which should be a bit slower. On the other hand his code removes the elements immediately and results in a cleansed soup object, while my code produces a list of unwanted items

Comment: @cullan 1.23 ms (mine) vs 1.33 ms + (other overheads to remove stuff)  (adam's)